# Get date and time from created_at field

Tags: php, laravel, date, time

How to extract date and time from created_at field in the database,

```
'issued_at'=> $order->created_at
```

above code-segment gives the following output

```
"issued_at":{"date":"2018-11-01 15:19:27.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"}}
```

But I just wanted to extract date and time, how can I do that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laravel/Eloquent uses the [Carbon library](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) for their timestamps, so you can use their methods:

```
$order->created_at->toDateString(); // 2018-11-01
$order->created_at->toTimeString(); // 15:19:27
$order->created_at->toDateTimeString() // 2018-11-01 15:19:27
```